# Issues with Longest Increasing Subsequence - Naive Approach

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence

I was learning the fundamentals of dynamic programming and came over to the [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent) of finding the Longest Increasing Subsequence in an array. Before looking up the DP solution, I decided to code it myself and came up with the following algorithm, the complete code to which can be found [here](http://ideone.com/vuIHb2).

The idea is to create a List Array to store all the increasing subsequences, and store the corresponding max value of each subsequence for faster comparisons.

```
private void findLIS(int[] inputArr) {
    List[] listOfSubs = new ArrayList[inputArr.length];    //Max different subsequences in an array would be N
    //To store the max value of each of the subsequences found yet
    List<Integer> maxValList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfSubs[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfSubs[0].add(inputArr[0]);    //Add the first element of the array to the list
    maxValList.add(inputArr[0]);

    for (int i=1;i<inputArr.length;i++) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int iter=0;

        //Compare inputArr[i] with the maxVal of each subsequence
        for (int j=0; j<maxValList.size(); j++) {
            if (inputArr[i]>maxValList.get(j)) {
                maxValList.set(j, inputArr[i]); //Update the maxVal in the corresponding position in the list
                listOfSubs[j].add(inputArr[i]);
                flag = true;
            }
            iter = j;
        }
        //If inputArr[i] is not greater than any previous values add it to a new list
        if (!flag) {
            maxValList.add(inputArr[i]);
            listOfSubs[iter+1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            listOfSubs[iter+1].add(inputArr[i]);
        }
    }

    //Finding the maximum length subsequence among all the subsequences
    int max=0, iter=0, index=0;
    for (List<Integer> lst : listOfSubs) {
        if (lst!=null && lst.size() > max) {
            max = lst.size();
            index=iter;
        }
        iter++;
    }

    //Print the longest increasing subsequence found
    System.out.println("The Longest Increasing Subsequence is of length " + listOfSubs[index].size() +
            " and is as follows:");
    for (int i=0;i<listOfSubs[index].size();i++) {
        System.out.print(listOfSubs[index].get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

The code runs in O(n^2) time and works perfectly for small/medium sized inputs. However, when I try running the code against some of the online practice portals (like [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent)), I get both TLE (Time Limit Exceeded Errors) and Wrong Answer. I understand the TLE errors, as the efficient solution is a DP O(nlogn) solution, but I'm confused about the wrong answers generated by this algorithm. Since, the inputs for such cases are too big (~10000), I'm unable to manually verify the where the solution goes wrong.

The complete code plus the output to one of the data sets can be found [here](http://ideone.com/vuIHb2). The correct answer should be 195 as reported by HackerRank.

Comment: off topic: n^2 solution passes all tests in hackerrank

Comment: @Yerken Why is this an off-topic question ? It satisfies all the guidelines set in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in as well as http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Plus, in the last link I'm showing a scenario where the problem is reproducible. 
I believe my solution is also an O(n^2) solution ?

Comment: `Why is this an off-topic question?` I consider it borderline: essential parts are expected _in_ the question to keep it self-contained when links go stale. You describe what you do to solve the problem, but not what the result is/why that solves (should solve)  the problem. I'm missing at least the WA output (20). (I'm surprised at the output format you use/show.)

Comment: @ShubhamMittal I am not saying ur question is off-topic, my comment is off-topic, just letting u know that n^2 solution passes all tests on Hackerrank, so the TLE is probably due to poor implementation

Comment: @Yerken Apologies! I noticed a vote to close the question (off-topic) and your comment thereafter and thus naturally linked the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem with my solution. The problem is because of not reading the problem statement carefully.

Say we consider the input as {3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1}. I only consider the sequences {3,6} and {2,6} in my code, but not sequences {2,4,5} or {3,4,5}. Thus, at every iteration if I find a number greater than the max of the previous subsequences, I add it to all such subsequences thereby diminishing the possibility of reaching the latter subsequences.